# Auto-Completion

Tags: algorithm, autocomplete, nosql

How does Google or amazon implement the auto-suggestion at their search box. I am looking for the algorithm with technology stack.

PS: I have searched over the net and found [this](http://www.quora.com/Google-Autocomplete/How-does-Googles-autocomplete-feature-work) and [this](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2010/09/google-instant-behind-scenes.html) and many many more. But I am more interested in not what they do but how they do it. NoSQL database to store the phases? or is it sorted or hashed according to keyword's? So to rephrase the question: Given the list of different searches ignoring personalization, geographic-location etc, How do they store, manage and suggest it so well.

Comment: You'd need to ask a Google engineer, and they may not tell you the answer...

Comment: If someone knew it as a single person, that person would either be dead, or very rich I think. (How on Earth did this question get an upvote?)

Answer (score 2):

This comes under the domain of `stastical language processing problems`. Take a look at [spelling suggestion article by Norvig](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). Auto - completion will use a similar mechanism. 
The idea is that from past searches, you know the probability of phrases (or better called bigram, trigram, ngram). For each such phrase, the auto complete selects the one having max value of

```
P(phrase|word_typed) = P(word_typed|phrase) P(phrase) / P(word_typed) 
P(phrase|word_typed) = Probability that phrase is right phrase if word typed 
so far is word_typed
```

Norvig's article is a very accessible and great explanation of this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Google takes your input and gives TOP4 RESULTS ACCORDING TO THE RANK IDs [if results are less it returns parameters as empty strings] given to different keywords which differ dynamically by the hit and miss count.
Then, they make a search query and returns 4 fields with url, title, and 2 more fields in Json, omnibox then populates the data using prepopulate functions in Chrome trunk.